# What is stereoscopic shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

These days, I am making some shaders such that Phong, Gourard, even Toon Shader in GLSL.

I have a curious question, I want to make a stereoscopic shader which using 2 camera, and left camera takes red light and right camera takes cyan light can be implemented by using combined them in one camera, so It can be a stereoscopic shader. I think.

Do I think wrong or not? I want to implement in 3D object which consists of 2D primitives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably need to render the scene twice, once for the left eye and once for the right eye. You can then blend the 2 together.

One way would be to render each eye into a different texture-backed FBO, and then combine those 2 textures into 1 either using a custom shader or even using additive blending, if you can render each eye with the correct colors to begin with. (If the left eye is truly only the red channel and the right is only the green and blue channels, an additive blend should do the right thing, I think.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an anaglyph imagage, using OpenGL lights to color the scene is stupid. 
Either use the method descibed in the other answer, i.e. using FBOs to render the scene into textures, then combine the results in a shader, or by simply drawing them on two overlaid quads in glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE) mode with modulated colors. Or, in case of red-cyan anaglyph you can use glColorMask to select which color channels are going to be written to.